# help with string patterns and RemoveCellTags

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I am building a table of contents using AuthorTools.  I used it to create cell tags so the TOC can make hyperlinks, but then I decided I wanted to change them.  But I am having trouble removing the old tags.

Here's what I did, after first making a few sample Section and Subsection cells:

```
<< AuthorTools`
nb = Notebooks[][[1]]
Paginate[nb]
MakeContents[nb, "Book", CellTagPrefix -> "c:"]
```

That worked as desired (and it made tag names like "c:1", "c:2"), but then I decided I wanted to change the prefix to "toc:".  To remove the old tags, I tried:

```
RemoveCellTags[nb, StringExpression["c:", __]]
```

but it didn't change any cell's tags.  The following did work, however, to remove just one tag:

```
RemoveCellTags[nb, "c:1"]
```

So I think I am using `StringExpression` wrong.  And yet, this works fine:

```
StringCases[{"c:3", "c:4"}, StringExpression["c:", __] ]
(* OUTPUT: {{"c:3"}, {"c:4"}}  *)
```

So, what should the input be to `RemoveCellTags` to get rid of all tags that start with "c:"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That package was written some time ago and has not been maintained. You'll need to make the following changes to the Common.m file in the package:

Find this code in the file

```
RemoveCellTags[nb_NotebookObject?NotebookOpenQ, pat_String] :=
Block[{tags},
  tags = NotebookCellTags[nb]//Flatten//Union;
  tags = Select[tags, StringMatchQ[#, pat]&];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  SelectionRemoveCellTags[nb, tags];
  nb
]
```

and change it to

```
RemoveCellTags[nb_NotebookObject?NotebookOpenQ, pat:(_String|_StringExpression)] :=
Block[{tags},
  tags = NotebookCellTags[nb]//Flatten//Union;
  tags = Select[tags, StringMatchQ[#, pat]&];
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  SelectionRemoveCellTags[nb, tags];
  nb
]
```

When I did that it worked fine for me

Comment: And for the record, I found that Common.m file (on the Mac) in: /Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/AddOns/Applications/AuthorTools